# is This @"Test Test Sample" kind of reportSuiteId valid or invalid for Adobe omniture  app tracking?

Tags: iphone, adobe-analytics

I just want to know that whether this **@"Test Test Sample"** is valid reportSuiteID, Does a report suit ID which have space,will be valid or invalid.

When i send request, i got nothing and my client told me that he has nothing to see in report.

I used below code

```
s = [[AppMeasurement alloc] init];
    s.debugTracking = YES;
    //Setup application config variables
    s.account = @"Test Test Sample"; 
    s.ssl = YES;
    s.dc = @"112";
    s.pageName = @"HelooPage"; 
    [s track];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The s.account variable is used to specify a report suite ID (RSID). RSIDs determine what set of reports to populate in SiteCatalyst, and do not contain spaces.

The string 'test test sample' is an invalid RSID - I would recommend getting a valid report suite from the client, such as a report suite dedicated to dev testing. That way you can send as much data to SiteCatalyst as you'd like without populating any important reports.